# Python win32, reading outlook

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I need to access the inbox folder of my third mail account on Outlook. The code I have tried is the following:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders["email@email.com"].Folders['Inbox']
message = inbox.Items
print (message)
print (message.Subject)
```

I get the following error:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)
```

Can anyone explain/fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are accessing a non-default folder, try to avoid using any folder or store names. Replace the line

```
inbox = outlook.Folders["email@email.com"].Folders['Inbox']
```

with the following (6 is `olFolderInbox`)

```
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
```

Also note that your (misnamed) `message` variable points to the `Items` collection, not a `MailItem` object. You need to iterate over that collection to access the items.